# What Is packageappinstaller for android? What other kind of apps are available?

Tags: android, google-chrome, apk, webpack-4, packageinstaller

I'm curious as to what packageappinstaller can do and what kind of apps are available through. Also what is an apk and what's its purpose?

Just need an explanation